# How to add dataGridView to new form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to add a `dataGridView` to a new `Form` that is created when i click a button.

Here is how i am creating the `Form`.

```
         if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns[16].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            int numberRow = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
            var form2 = new Form();
            form2.Show();

            var historygridview = new DataGridView();

            var dt = sIMSDataSet.History;
            var dv = new DataView(dt);

            var SMNumber = dataGridView1.Rows[numberRow].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            dv.RowFilter = "SM = " + "'" + SMNumber + "'";
            historygridview.DataSource = dv;
        }
```

I have setup the `dataGridView` called `historyGridView` how do i add that to `form2`?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it was pretty easy. just needed to add this.

form2.Controls.Add(historygridview);